# Painting over a GridView

Tags: android, gridview, paint

I've got a GridView which is displaying a calendar. I need to draw some fat lines (about 1/4 of the height of a grid cell) across multiple 'days', and possibly across multiple weeks. I may need to do two or three of these for any given week.

Each line across the cells of a week will need to have some text in it as well.

Since the lines need to cross grid cells I though perhaps I could get a Canvas for the GridView and paint on that. But I can't find a way to do that. Since the lines cross multiple grid cells it doesn't seem useful to draw the line in a particular cell and try to line it up with the previous cell. And I have to do this dynamically, I can't set it in the layout.

I'm open to ideas about how to make this work. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do any additional drawing on top of the GridView content:

- Override dispatchDraw(), which hands you a Canvas to draw on.
- Call super.dispatchDraw() to draw the normal content first.
- Use the Canvas to add anything additional you feel necessary.

HTH

Comment: Ok, so to override dispatchDraw() I have to subclass GridView. How do I specify that in the layout? Will it understand if I give it the name of my class instead of GridView? Or will I have to leave it out and inflate the view manually?

Comment: Take a look at the SDK article for custom controls.  Specifically, at the bottom of the article it shows you how to utilize a custom View class you create in your XML layout: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#modifying